# Invalid type ScheduleBatch

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

Im trying to write a testsclass but getting the error: Invalid type: ScheduleBatch. Line 8

My Class:

```
    global class DeleteRecords implements Schedulable{
        global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
            List<Lot__c> customObj = [select Id FROM Lot__c WHERE Name != ''];
            if(!customObj.isEmpty())
        delete customObj;
    }
}
```

My TestClass

```
@isTest
public class testScheduleBatch{  

    public static testmethod void DeleteRecords(){
        Test.startTest();
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addMinutes(1);
        String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ dt.minute() + ' * ' + dt.day() + ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year();
        testScheduleBatch.SchedulerMethod('Test Deleterecords', CRON_EXP, new ScheduleBatch() );   
        Test.stopTest();
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing `DeleteRecords`, why do you schedule `ScheduleBatch` class? 
In addition unit-tests are design to check behavior of code. So asserts are required. In this case you can check that job is started and that proper records are deleted.

```
@isTest
public class testScheduleBatch{  

    @isTest
    private static void DeleteRecords(){
        insert new Lot__c(
            Name = 'Some Name'
            );//create test data 
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addMinutes(1);
        String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ dt.minute() + ' * ' + dt.day() + ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year();
        Test.startTest();
            String jobId = System.schedule('Test Deleterecords', CRON_EXP, new DeleteRecords() );   
        Test.stopTest();
        CronTrigger ct = [
            select Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
            from CronTrigger
            where id = :jobId
            ];
        System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);
        List<Lot__c> actual = [
            select Id
            from Lot__c
            where Name != ''
            ];
        System.assertEquals(true, actual.isEmpty());
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Im new to schedulers so I missed that one think I have a better understanding now THX!